# Rails migration rollback mistake - how to update schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I royally screwed up with version control and deleted a bunch of files including migrations. I tried then to rails generate the files with the same names but then got (error, record already exists). I realized the table must already exist in the database.

If I run `rake db:migrate:status` I get the following:

```
up     20150426172505  Remove columns from businesses categories sub categories
up    20150426172902  Change pdf name
up     20150520193556  ********** NO FILE **********
up     20150520194841  ********** NO FILE **********
up     20150527194215  ********** NO FILE **********
```

How do I get rid of the missing migrations and get the schema to use 20150426172902?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways you can get rid of those *lost* migration files.

One is to run the following command:

```
rake db:migrate:reset db:seed
```

This will completely drop down your database, re-run all the migration, and run the seeds if you have any.

Second is to run the following query, and directly deleting the lost migration files that you do not want to see around.

```
DELETE FROM `schema_migrations` WHERE version='<MIGRATION_ID>';
```